# How do I Log selenium RC output

Tags: selenium-rc

I have a test hub .Net application which can fire off different selenium tests.

I'm looking for a good way to record the results of that specific test and tell the user if there has been an error.

I've added the "-log selenium.log -browserSideLog line"  but, can I access the log programatically?

The idea being that at the tear down stage I can look at the entries and search for "Error" and report this to the user.

I know there is the "RetrieveLastRemoteControlLogs" command but that only gets part of log.

Answer (score 0):

if you know PowerShell, then you can to use cmdlet get-content. 
In .Net you can to use methods from the class File [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.aspx), but i dont work with it.
you can run "get-content" after each test and check whether there are errors

if i  have not answered your question, then you can add tags, because it is not only selenium-rc`s question.